# Is it possible to determine the largest font size that will fit inside of a JLabel based on the label's height?

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a program that uses Swing components for the GUI and I want it to look good on as many different resolutions as possible without actually defining specific parameters for each one.

I already have it set up so that a JLabel takes up a constant proportion of the screen in terms of width and height, but while the size stays roughly the same, the size of the text can change dramatically because at the moment I have it so the font size is set to a constant value that has nothing to do with resolution (other than that it's just what looks good on my screen).

To elaborate, if you're dealing with similar resolutions like the 2 most common I've found my friends to have (1366x768 and 1920x1080), it's not that big of a deal, but now I've found one of my friends has a resolution of 3840x2160. The components are in the same location and are the same sizes with their resolution as someone with 1920x1080, but the text is 1/4 the size.

So how can I find the largest font size that will fit inside of any given JLabel?

(Just for maximum clarification, I'm not concerned with whether or not the string in the label is too long to be displayed completely, I'm solely focusing on how the text fits vertically)

Comment: IMO think that's the wrong question to ask. We already have paradigms for "Responsive Design" that tackle portability of your application to various form factors, (i.e. phone, tablet and laptop). You should not solve the problem at such a granular level when there are already holistic solutions available that solve the problem in the design phase itself.

Comment: In most cases, you shouldn't be doing that.  You should avoid setting the JLabel's font altogether.  That way, it will pick up the font size of the current desktop theme, whose font the user can adjust as desired.

Comment: Swing is not going to look good on retina size monitors.  Swing was developed long before retina size monitors were available.  You can try JavaFX or [Apache Pivot](https://pivot.apache.org/).

Comment: @VGR Using the current desktop theme wouldn't be ideal for this case because I want the text to take up a specified ratio of the window's height. If I don't change the font size then it could be anything, which would more often than not make the GUI look disgusting.

Comment: It is, the simple method would be to use `FontMetrics` and a simple `while-loop` and loop over a range of font sizes until the `textHeight` + `ascent` is either equal to or greater than your requirements, this is somewhat slow. You might be able to use a binary search style algorithm instead, but you'd have to play around with that